# Adding a counter to a Quick Sort algorithm to display the total number of swap actions

Tags: c#, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to add a counter to my quicksort algorithm to display the total number of swaps performed on a given array. However, I am having no luck and an obvious incorrect value (14) is being generated.

The array being manipulated is 'arr' which is a collection of 128 decimal numbers;

1.960 
2.010 
2.020 
1.940 
2.030 
2.050 
2.000 
1.890 
1.860 
1.960 
1.990 
2.010 
2.010 
2.010 
1.960 
1.940 
1.920 
1.930 
1.980 
1.960 
1.940 
1.900 
1.860 
1.890 
1.860 
1.860 
1.820 
1.810 
1.790 
1.750 
1.780 
1.850 
1.790 
1.790 
1.780 
1.770 
1.760 
1.770 
1.670 
1.610 
1.610 
1.590 
1.540 
1.520 
1.510 
1.540 
1.620 
1.600 
1.560 
1.570 
1.470 
1.420 
1.440 
1.410 
1.450 
1.370 
1.340 
1.320 
1.330 
1.430 
1.440 
1.430 
1.470 
1.480 
1.510 
1.570 
1.630 
1.680 
1.720 
1.710 
1.670 
1.650 
1.620 
1.610 
1.560 
1.580 
1.570 
1.630 
1.640 
1.720 
1.750 
1.750 
1.680 
1.610 
1.620 
1.600 
1.570 
1.510 
1.530 
1.520 
1.550 
1.550 
1.670 
1.650 
1.540 
1.560 
1.710 
1.860 
1.830 
1.670 
1.750 
1.760 
1.780 
1.890 
2.010 
2.010 
1.970 
1.980 
2.040 
2.020 
2.020 
2.020 
2.080 
2.080 
2.080 
2.100 
2.170 
2.160 
2.150 
2.150 
2.120 
2.110 
2.090 
2.130 
2.150 
2.110 
2.100 
2.120

Here is the code

```
  int n = arr.Length;
  int step = 0;
  int totalsteps = Quick_Sort(arr, 0, n - 1, step);
  Console.WriteLine("Number of steps = {0}", totalsteps);

 private static int Quick_Sort(decimal[] arr, int left, int right, int step)
    {
        int i, j;
        decimal pivot, temp;
        i = left;
        j = right;
        pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
        do
        {
            while ((arr[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
            while ((pivot < arr[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
            if (i <= j)
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
                step++;
            }
        } while (i <= j);
        if (left < j) Quick_Sort(arr, left, j, step);
        if (i < right) Quick_Sort(arr, i, right, step);
        return step;
    }
```

**SOLVED**: passed the step value by reference and now works as expected

Comment: can u give an example of ur expected result ?

Comment: The function is called recursively. Try to make your step parameter ref, or sum return from other calls, otherwise you get only result from first dive

Comment: @Viliam made the step parameter ref and it now works. Thanks

Comment: When adding statistical type counters to existing code, it's usually better to use global variables rather than change all of the function interfaces. This reduces the amount of code that needs to be changed, and makes it easier to use conditional compile (#if ...) to enable / disable these type of counters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 possible solutions to this

**Return value**

```
private static int Quick_Sort(decimal[] arr, int left, int right)
{
   int step = 0;
   int i, j;
   decimal pivot, temp;
   i = left;
   j = right;
   pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
   do
   {
      while ((arr[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
      while ((pivot < arr[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
      if (i <= j)
      {
         temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[j];
         arr[j] = temp;
         i++;
         j--;
         step++;
      }
   } while (i <= j);
   if (left < j) step += Quick_Sort(arr, left, j, step);
   if (i < right) step += Quick_Sort(arr, i, right, step);
   return step;
}
```

**Reference value**

```
private static void Quick_Sort(decimal[] arr, int left, int right, ref int step)
{
   int i, j;
   decimal pivot, temp;
   i = left;
   j = right;
   pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
   do
   {
      while ((arr[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
      while ((pivot < arr[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
      if (i <= j)
      {
         temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[j];
         arr[j] = temp;
         i++;
         j--;
         step++;
      }
   } while (i <= j);
   if (left < j)  Quick_Sort(arr, left, j, ref step);
   if (i < right)  Quick_Sort(arr, i, right, ref step);

}
```

**Global variable**

```
private int _step= 0;

private static void Quick_Sort(decimal[] arr, int left, int right)
{
   int i, j;
   decimal pivot, temp;
   i = left;
   j = right;
   pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
   do
   {
      while ((arr[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
      while ((pivot < arr[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
      if (i <= j)
      {
         temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[j];
         arr[j] = temp;
         i++;
         j--;
         _step++;
      }
   } while (i <= j);
   if (left < j)  Quick_Sort(arr, left, j );
   if (i < right)  Quick_Sort(arr, i, right);
}
```

**Original answer**

You are not adding the result back to `step` from the recursion

```
if (left < j) step += Quick_Sort(arr, left, j, step);
if (i < right) step += Quick_Sort(arr, i, right, step);
```

Comment: Just attempted this but now the number of steps is at -888846434 so something else has gone Pete tong

Comment: It did not work, because the counter STEP did not start from zero, but was passed as already incremented into recursions. If the step was localized and started from zero, it would be ok.

Comment: @Viliam thanks, it's 1am in the morning here and not in front of the pc, but that makes sense. Write up the answer